# Integer division rounding down in C# (for negatives)

Tags: c#, math

Is there any way to perform integer dividing in C# (without float or decimal, I need to keep this one very fast) that rounds down the number?

The default division just discards fraction argument. Consider:

```
 1 / 2 = 0 // That is correct
-1 / 2 = 0 // ... but I want to get (-1) here!
```

My division will take both positive and negative numbers for dividor. I need not to employ `if`, as branching will be too costly (the operation will be run very frequently in realtime game engine)...

Comment: Subtract 1 from the negative number before dividing it (don't do this for non-negative numbers)

Comment: @elgonzo I don't know if the number is negative. It can be both positive and negative

Comment: Of course you can know this, in other words your code can figure out whether a number is negative or not...

Comment: What is it about floats that you think is slow? You might be imagining a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: @elgonzo I need `if` or any other form of branching for that, which is very costly operation

Comment: @Crowcoder Give me a float that works without.. well, floating for int.max :)

Comment: "floating for int.max"? What does that mean? Floats are ones and zeros just like ints. I could see you not wanting to use `Decimal` but floats and doubles won't slow you down.

Comment: @elgonzo Oh, that's nice one! Can you post this as answer?

Comment: @Crowcoder floats loses precision near 10,000,000. Integer can go much higher than that. I would need double, and this actually takes even more computing time for FPU

Comment: @PiotrK, yeah, give me i minute...

Comment: You wouldn't lose enough precision to affect the integral part of the value. I don't know what you are trying to accomplish so I can't say how you should do it but floating point math is not slow.

Comment: @Crowcoder Give it a try, it will affect integral part. Near int.max :) FPU calculation is definitely slower then just ALU operation. And this code will be executed really frequently...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dividing by 2 is a simple bitwise right-shift. After @elgonzo's (now deleted) mention of the properties of C#'s rightshift, I decided to have a look how it works, and it *seems* to do exactly what you want:

```
var result = number >> 1;
```

This gives the following results:

11 -> 5
10 -> 5
2  -> 1
1  -> 0
-1 -> -1
-2 -> -1
-32 -> -16
-33 -> -17

int.MaxValue and MinValue also work.

Performance-wise, this seems to be almost twice as fast as the currently accepted answer that uses modulo operators.
Dividing (the same) 100000000 random numbers costs 2.17 seconds on my machine using a simple shift, while using the version with modulo's takes between 3.1 and 4.0 seconds.

The branched versions seem to perform just about the same as the modulo version: significantly slower than the simple rightshift.

Comment: Dang! Not being able to see the forest for all the trees. Here, have my upvote. (For what's worth, i have deleted my over-complicated answer, in an attempt to not distract from the simplicity of the solution. Man, am i allowed to blame the weekend for that? ;-P )

Comment: @elgonzo Well, you did point me in the right direction, thanks for that :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to divide `a` by `b`:

**The approach which won't fail because of overflow:**

```
int res = a / b;
return (a < 0 && a != b * res) ? res - 1 : res;
```

**The following approaches may possibly fail because of negative overflow.**

```
int mod = a % b;
if (mod < 0) {
  mod += b;
}
return (a - mod) / b;
```

A mess with `mod += b` because `a % b` can be negative.
A shorter way:

```
return (a - (a % b + b) % b) / b;
```

And more clear one:

```
return a >= 0 ? a / b : (a - b + 1) / b;
```

Comment: I just understood that there is a risk of negative overflow.

Comment: Note that modulo operations _might_ be more costly than a simple branching when considering CPU branch prediction capabilities (possible impacts on branch prediction performance gains due to mitigations for certain recent CPU vulnerabilities such as Spectre/Meltdown not withstanding)

Comment: 3 versions use branching, and the fourth uses 2 modulo-operations. I would suggest testing for performance...

Comment: After testing, it looks like all of these options are significantly slower than a simple `n>>1`, while doing the same job.

Comment: @oerkelens, Well, of course. But `n >> 1` divides only by `2`. You have to handle other integers.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the case (OP seems slightly unclear on that). But in that case, OP's aversion to branching seems unfounded because it doesn't perform better than the alternatives :)